# Any zero knowledge proof system for the Set Cover Problem?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Since the Set Cover Problem is an NP problem, Zero Knowledge System for Set Cover will definitely exist, but I cannot find such a proof system.

Comment: I'm guessing that for some reason the generic answer of "reduce to, say, Hamiltonian cycle and use a ZK proof for that" is not satisfactory?